# How to integrate full text search in Spring-data-jpa?

Tags: spring, full-text-search, hibernate-search, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to integrate full text search with spring data jpa? I am used to use [hibernate search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) in my project.

**Hibernate search**(*Hibernate Search brings the power of full text search engines to the persistence domain model by combining Hibernate Core with the capabilities of the Apache Lucene™ search engine.*) can work with traditional jpa  properly.

Now I am going to move to spring data jpa.What's the best practice to implement full text search?

Comment: Are you implying that Hibernate Search won't work with Spring Data?

Answer (score 3):

Using Spring Data JPA shouldn't make any difference regarding the usage of your domain model for indexing. It's a thin layer on top of JPA to ease query execution to the most part.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider solr as described [here](http://adeithzya.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/using-apache-solr-with-spring-framework/)

Comment: I have read that article, it's good, and can be one option. But I want to use solr or lucence indirectly and transparently. Hibernate search is not good enough, but at least I won't need to write code for index every time one bean created.

Comment: You are right. Goodluck in this case and I hope when you find a way you'd share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

This project [here](http://code.google.com/p/sol-dock-r/) is built upon solrj and spring but does not have a spring-data integration yet. So you'll still have to take care of indexing yourself. 
But nevertheless you may want to have a look.

Comment: Thanks,I will take a look at this project. And I am going to use jpa data for "direct search",and use solr itself directly for full text search.